# react not rendering on WP - could be @wordpress/element vs import ReactDOM

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I have been trying to render a component (FlighContainer) through react on wordpress homepage but unable to do so . I do not see any error in console but also do not see component mounted. My index.js is . I think it might have to do something with using  `import { render, Component } from "@wordpress/element";` vs. `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` , but I am not sure. If I use `[wp-element]` as dependency in functions.php lines (mentioned below) , I get error `Target container is not a DOM element.` and  `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')` .  can anyone clarify why do they use one or the other and how do I resolve my issue or rendering

```
    import HomePageFlightContainer from './HomePageFlightContainer';
    import PageFetch from './PageFetch';
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    const App = () => {
        return (
            <Router >                  
                    <Switch>
                       <Route path="/wordpress/search" component={PageFetch} />
                       <Route  path="/" component={HomePageFlightContainer} /> 
                    </Switch>               
            </Router>
        );
    };

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and FlighContainer.js is

```
import HomePageFlightContainer from './HomePageFlightContainer';
        import React from 'react';
        const FlighContainer = () => {
            return (
                <div>
                    < HomePageFlightContainer />
                </div>
            );
        };
        ReactDOM.render(<FlighContainer />, document.getElementById('search-flights-container'));
```

index.php is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php language_attributes(); ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./dist/js/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/js/FlighContainerBundle.js"></script>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

functions.php is

```
 wp_enqueue_style('theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/css/style.bundle.css', array(), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('FlighContainerBundle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/FlighContainerBundle.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpackConfig = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        bundle: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
        FlighContainerBundle: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'FlighContainer.js')
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as those errors and rendering is concerned , I got it resolved by using `Routes` instead of `Switch`

```
    import { BrowserRouter,  Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    export const App = () => {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter >          
                    <Routes>
                       <Route path="/wordpress/search" component={PageFetch}  /> 
                       <Route  path="/" component={HomePageFlightContainer} /> 
                    </Routes>             
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('search-flights-container')); 
ReactDOM.render(<HomePageFlightContainer />, document.getElementById('search-flights-container'));
```

and wrapping the component in `<BrowserRouter>` like `return ( <BrowserRouter> ... </BrowserRouter>);` specially if you plan to use `Link` in the component

I rendered both in the same element (before I was trying to render HomePageFlightContainer by creating second entry point through webpack.config.js). But I can see visually what I was expecting by rendering above code.

Questions still unanswered:

- what effects will it have by not using second entry point for `HomePageFlightContainer`
- Also looking for an answer about the use of `@wordpress/element` vs `import ReactDOM` in react component

But I did use this in functions.php ( Note: `['wp-element']`)

```
  wp_enqueue_script('bundle.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/bundle.js',  ['wp-element'], '1.0', true);
```